# Delete cache on ipad safari

Tags: ios, ipad, caching, mobile-safari, web-sql

I am developing application that utilizes `WebSQL` database. It appears that I have screwed up database structure (pretty strong assumption), but I am unsure how exactly I have done that. In such cases on chrome I simply clear browser history, cache, temp data and I am good to go to recreate database from scratch. I have page that on landing runs all the scripts on empty database and populates it with data.
When testing on IPad it becomes more complicated as I am unable to see the structure of database to write a script to solve the problem and 'drop all everything' script does not seem to do it.
At this point my gut tells me that fastest way to my salvation is to clear the cache on browser on IPad Safari.
**How to I clear the browser cache on IPad?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself.

```
Settings > Safari > [Clear History], [Clear Cookies and Data]
```

[image]